# Are runtime permissions practically obligatory for work with pools?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I am making a `ThreadPoolExecutor` in Java SE now. Reading the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html), I have found an interesting detail:

> Threads should possess the "modifyThread" RuntimePermission. If worker
>   threads or other threads using the pool do not possess this
>   permission, service may be degraded: configuration changes may not
>   take effect in a timely manner, and a shutdown pool may remain in a
>   state in which termination is possible but not completed.

In other words, it behaves **strange**, what is unacceptable.

Does that mean that without setting "`modifyThread`" `RuntimePermission` I can't normally use the `ThreadPoolExecutor`?